Translate-z-[100px] doesn't work in Tailwind css
I use the follwoing code to 3-d rotating in Tailwind :
<span className='absolute whitespace-nowrap transform-style-3d translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] rotate-x-[0deg] translate-z-[100px]'> Hello World</span>
<span className='absolute whitespace-nowrap transform-style-3d translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] rotate-x-[72deg] translate-z-[100px]'> Hello World</span>
<span className='absolute whitespace-nowrap transform-style-3d translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] rotate-x-[144deg] translate-z-[100px]'> Hello World</span>
...

But no change occurs on the z-axis.By the way I installed "npm install -D tailwindcss-3d" and add it in tailwind.config.js file in this way :
plugins: [ require('tailwindcss-3d')],

Thanks!

According to the MDN guide on translateZ, for the translate-z transformation to work, the element must be wrapped in a parent that has the perspective CSS property applied. Additionally, the element being transformed along the z-axis needs the transform-style property set to preserve-3d.
In Tailwind CSS, this can be implemented as follows:
<div class="perspective-500">
  <span class='absolute whitespace-nowrap transform-style-3d translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] rotate-x-[144deg] translate-z-[100px]'> Hello World</span>
</div>

You can play around with the code here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/TrYnA3H7UU
